# Using const inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Let's say I have the following code

```
for (let i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    //Get row from MongoDB
    **const** foo = Collection.find({index:i});
}
```

vs

```
for (let i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    //Get row from MongoDB
    **let** foo = Collection.find({index:i});
}
```

The only difference is that `foo` is using `const` vs `let`.

**How does Node handle this in memory?**

I would've imagined it doesn't make a difference because the `const`s would just get redeclared and versions of previous iterations would just get freed in memory by `GC`. Is this not the case though? I'm trying to debug a memory leak and am wondering if simply changing the `const` to `let` will do the trick.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need help debugging a memory leak, you'll need to post the complete code that reproduces the issue, and make a heap snapshot to find from where the leaked memory is referenced.

Comment: How did you get the idea that this of all things is what would cause your memory leak? And again, you need to show us the code, if we should help you with the leak.

Answer (score 0):

`const` in block-scopes is always new, so there's literally no difference in there, except `const` guards the rest of the code within the for loop, so that you can't re-assign, even by accident, `foo`.

Block scopes are `for-of`, `for-in`, just `{ ... }`, closures scopes, etc, these are all the same, the `const` is valid per scope execution, unreachable outside, and unreachable in the next loop iteration.

```
for (const value of items) { ... }
for (const key in object) { ... }
{ const thing = 123; }
```

and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no difference for memory. `let` and `const` both are block-scoped declarations, so a separate variable is created for each iteration of the loop, and kept as long as anything references it.